# Canvas en diferentes views - Asp.net core MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvc, asp.net-core

Como puedo usar un canvas en diferentes views ( asp.net core MVC )
Os dejo aqui el pequeno ejemplo:

```
canvas width="500" height="400" id="signature"
            style="border:1px solid black"></canvas><br>
    <button type="button" id="accept"
            class="btn btn-primary">
        Accept signature
    </button>
  <br>
    <img width="500" height="400" id="savetarget"
         style="border:1px solid black"><br>
</p>
```

Despues este es el script para guardar la firma en imagen:

```
$(function () {

        var canvas = document.querySelector('#signature');
        var pad = new SignaturePad(canvas);

        $('#accept').click(function () {

            var data = pad.toDataURL();

            $('#savetarget').attr('src', data);
            $('#SignatureDataUrl').val(data);
            pad.off();

        });

    });
```

Y ahora lo que quiero es que en otra view pueda usar la misma imagen que guardo en #savetarget, estoy usando este codigo:

```
<p>
        <img width="500" height="400" id="savetarget"
             style="border:1px solid black">
    </p>
```

Lo veis posible con algun Jquery o AJAX, o entonces tengo que hacerlo pasar por un controlador y meterlo en algun model?, me gustaria que fuese temporal el guardado de la imagen.